# compare the files based on the first column of file1 and print the row which are not in other files

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have 7 files and would like to compare the first column of file1. I want to print the row if the first column's name from file1 does not appear in any other files.

```
file 1

peter 10  300
Xavier 12  30
Jack   123  67
Ram    34   57
Jancy   56  34
Thomson 56  67

file2

Jack    23  67
peter   12  39

file3 

Jack   123  67
peter  15   45
Thomson  35  430
```

I would like to get the following output

```
Xavier 12  30
Ram    34   57
Jancy   56  34
```

Your suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem so you can get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FILENAME != "file1" {a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file[2-6] file1
Xavier 12  30
Ram    34   57
Jancy   56  34
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my suggestion:

```
grep -v $(printf '-e ^%s ' $(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2 file3 | sort -u)) file1
```

Hope that helps.